# How do I find same lines in two files C++?

Tags: c++, compare

I need to write a program for my school project, which compares lines from two large files, one approx. 1.5G(40kk lines), and other one is approx. 5gb(100kk lines) to find duplicate lines and write those lines to new file.

I've already tried writing those programs in NodeJs and Python, however, they weren't able to compare those files, on Python it look like 30 minutes only to compare one line. Perhaps I was doing something wrong.

I wonder if C++ would be able to handle this task with ease, what's the fastest way to compare those files, any suggestions?

Comment: That depends, really. How much memory do you have at your disposal? Technically you could read both files into `std::map<std::string>`, which will perform sorting and then use `std::find` to check one line after the other. It will still take quite a while though.

Comment: If it took 30 minutes to compare a line you did something wrong. SInce the files are so large you cannot read in the files entirely in to memory, you'll have to read the files in sections. You may want to look in to memory mapped files in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Alternatively you can read just one of the files into memory and read the other 'line by line' to perform the searching. That should be easier on your memory, albeit not by 'much'.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I have 32gb of ram in my pc, Ryzen 7 3800x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to go about this and none of them are pretty.

I believe, one of the more efficient options goes about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream firstFile("firstFile");
    std::ifstream secondFile("secondFile");
    
    if (firstFile.is_open() && secondFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while(!secondFile.eof())
        {
            std::map<std::string, bool> stringMap;
            for (int i = 0; 
                i < 500000 && 
                !std::getline(secondFile, line).eof();
                ++i
            )
                stringMap[line] = false;

            while (!std::getline(firstFile, line).eof())
            {
                std::map<std::string, bool>::iterator it = stringMap.find(line);
                if (it != stringMap.end())
                    it->second = true;
            }

            firstFile.clear();      //Clears the eof Flag.
            firstFile.seekg(0);     //Rewinds to the beginning of the list.
            //Iterate over map and write all matches to the result file
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This (kinda pseudo) code will read the second file in chunks of 500k lines, performs a check against all lines of the first file and gives you a list of all lines that are in both files.

Completely untested though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, there are two errors. First, in line ```if (firstFile.open("firstFile") && secondFile.open("secondFile"))``` on firstFile and secondFile it says, quote: expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool), and the second one is in .feof calls, quote: class std::basic_ifstream has no member "feof". Any idea why that happened? It's my first time with C++, so I have no idea.

Comment: @Hje282 As I said, this is Pseudo-Code. I usually use the C-API to interact with files and the code is meant to illustrate the idea, not be 'copy -> paste -> it works'.
But let me fix the worst errors.

Comment: Alright, fixed the code, so it at least gets passed the compiler. The functionality remains completely untested though and it's still missing the 'write matches to file'. You're, of course, free to amend the `i < 500000` to whatever you think your machine can handle. The higher the number, the less iterations you'll need, the faster you'll be done.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying. Also thank you for accepting my answer, many newcomers forget that. :)